# Launch application on click of specific url

Tags: android, video, android-intent, browser, intentfilter

When any video url is clicked, on the android phone, I want my application to be displayed in popUp, which says, do you want to play the link using, chrome, or myApp..

I want this to happen only for specific Video links, like Youtube video URLs only. In short my application will work as an browser only for specific video links.
How should I achieve this.

Comment: http://paragchauhan2010.blogspot.com/2013/03/make-link-in-android-browser-start-up.html

Answer (score 1):

Look into [Intent Filters](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#ifs). You can use them to register your app to handle certain file types or specific url schemes.

Answer (score 1):

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
        <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.youtube.com" ></data>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

You might also want to use the same scheme for https and mobile, do not forget it ;-)

```
 <data android:host="www.youtube.com" android:scheme="http" />
 <data android:host="www.youtube.com" android:scheme="https" />
 <data android:host="m.youtube.com" android:scheme="http" />
 <data android:host="m.youtube.com" android:scheme="https" />
```